# There's no line here to end with a caption of tikzfigure

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzposter

When compiling the following MWE I get a "There's no line to end here" on line 15.
MWE:

```
\documentclass[a0poster]{tikzposter} % See Section 3
\title{MWE}
\author{Baaboo}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\maketitle[titletotopverticalspace=0pt,titletoblockverticalspace=15pt,innersep=0pt] % See Section 4.1
\block{Plot}{
\begin{tikzfigure}%[Ciao]
\include{graph_MWE}
\end{tikzfigure}
}
\end{document}
```

where graph_MWE is the following file:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\definecolor{steelblue31119180}{RGB}{31,119,180}

\begin{axis}[
width=25cm,
height=25cm
]
\addplot [semithick, steelblue31119180, mark=*, mark size=2, mark options={solid}, only marks]
table {%
-0.234033255900646 -1.00367625019002
};
\addlegendentry{point1}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The weird thing is that this error only happens when I use a caption through the option, on the tikzfigure environment (Try putting a "%" before "[Ciao]" and you get no error), and this caption works great if I include something else in the figure than the graph included, which also happens to work perfectly fine when included in a normal document in a classic figure environment. However, I cannot use a classic figure environment in a tikzposter.

Comment: You need to create a MINIMAL example showing your error. Delete all unneeded code. What does "use a caption on the tikzfigure" mean? `[...]` are options.

Comment: probably not related but do not use `\include`  like this `\include{graph_MWE}` include always starts and ends wtih `\clearpage` so should never be in a `tkzpicture` (or in any box at all) use `\input`

Comment: actually that is the issue, the error goes if you use `\input`

Comment: Just had time to make my example even more minimal following the first comment and you already solved it, thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use `\include` inside a box. It should be used for chapter level file inclusions and always starts and ends with `\clearpage`. Use `\input` here.